# Django REST Framework: Integrity error on not null column when posting data

Tags: django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have these two related models:

```
class EndPoint(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)   

class Parameter(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    required = models.BooleanField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    format = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True)
    endpoint = models.ForeignKey(EndPoint, related_name="parameters",null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Which map to these seralizers:

```
class ParameterRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parameter
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'label', 'required','type','format')
    
class EndPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parameters = ParameterRelationSerializer(many = True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = EndPoint
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'url', 'description', 'parameters')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        parameters = validated_data.pop('parameters')
        endPoint = EndPoint.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for parameter_relation in parameters:
            Parameter.objects.create(endpoint=endPoint, **parameter_relation)
        return endPoint
```

Now, when I try to POST a new endpoint with this data:

```
{
   "url":"http://the.url.com",
   "name":"Dummy url",
   "description":"This is a dummy url",
   "parameters":[
      {
         "name":"dummyparam",
         "type":"dummy",
         "label":"dummy_parameter"
      }
   ]
}
```

I get a 500 error saying this:

> IntegrityError at /catalogs/endpoints/
>
> null value in column "required" violates not-null constraint
>
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, 2017-08-14 12:01:52.857902+00, 2017-08-14 12:01:52.857984+00, dummyparam, dummy_parameter, null, dummy, null, 6).

Basically, it is complaining about the not-null 'required' attribute (in the Parameter model) being missing thus causing a DB error.

My question is, shouldn't this be handled by the serializer validator instead of throwing a DB exception? In fact, I have another bunch of not-null attributes that trigger a validation error when missing in the json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question -

> My question is, shouldn't this be handled by the serializer validator
>   instead of throwing a DB exception? In fact, I have another bunch of
>   not-null attributes that trigger a validation error when missing in
>   the json data.

The validators at serializer's end are executed only when that key is present in the request data. Since you are not passing that attribute "required" at all, hence no validators are being called at serializer end.

You should also tell your serializer about such fields with the help of extra_kwargs as shown below -

```
 extra_kwargs = {
     'required': {'required': True},
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve it using extra_kwargs. Still, there's something missing to make 100% sense. You say that validators run "only when that key is present in the request data", but it's weird cause like I said the others fields (for example, 'label') are not nullable and cause a validation error even when not present in the request. I guess it has something to do with BooleanFields specifically.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I will have to take a look again into this. Will update you once done.

Comment: I have a similar issue presently.Can you help me look into this please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62655168/not-null-constrained-error-on-field-handled-in-views-py

Answer (score 1):

you can try add is_valid()

```
ParameterRelationSerializer
for parameter_relation in parameters:
        parameter_relation.update({"endpoint":endPoint})
        serializer = ParameterRelationSerializer(data=parameter_relation)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
```

of if you need it, you may add raise validation exeption:

```
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
```